# Counting duplicate tags in a string of many tags

Tags: php

I have a photo list page where each photo has multiple tags (as spaced words). I'm trying to display most of the tags on the page after:

- Removing duplicate tags
- Sorting tags by having most occurring tags first

The code looks like this:

```
$tags1 = "red blue green yellow colors";
$tags2 = "blue green grass tree garden";    
$tags3 = "pink blue colors paint sky"

addTags($tags1);
addTags($tags2);
addTags($tags3);
echo (processTags());

private $tagsArray;
public function addTags($param) {
    if($param == ""){ // no tags
        return;
    }
    $explode = explode(" ",$param);
    $this->tagsArray = array_merge($this->tagsArray, $explode);
}

private function processTags(){
    $processedTags = array_count_values($this->tagsArray);
    arsort($processedTags);
    $count = 0;
    foreach($processedTags as $tag => $value) { 
        if(++$count>50) break; // don't print more than 50 tags
        $output .= "<a href=\"/tags/$tag\">$tag</a>";
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Each photo can have dozens of tags and there can be hundreds of tags total. Is there any way to improve the code to make it more *efficient*? Could it be done with less code? The above code works just fine, but I'm just curious to know if there is a better way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

I has been a long time since I used PHP, but **what you want are [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)#Multiset) that are basically sets with a value -> number-of-occurrences mapping**. I believe you can accomplish this in PHP via associative arrays as below:

```
$tags1 = "red blue green yellow colors blue red green yellow yellow";

function addTags($param) {

    // tagsArray should be a global variable
    // but put as local variable for illustration only
    $tagsArray = array();

    if($param == ""){ // no tags
        return;
    }
    $explode = explode(" ",$param);

    foreach ($explode as $value) {
       $val = 0;
       if (array_key_exists($value, $tagsArray)) {
          $val = $tagsArray[$value];          
       }

       $tagsArray[$value] = 1 + $val;
    }

    // sort the array
    arsort($tagsArray);

    // for illustration purposes only
    foreach ($tagsArray as $key => $value) {
       echo $key.':'.$value.', ';
    }
}

addTags($tags1);
```

Comment: Thanks Jamal, your editing was very awesome and highly appreciated! Cheers! :)